# where to place transactions in DAO pattern

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dao

Where does one implement transactions in an android app using DAO pattern?

Suppose i have a domain class A and a corresponding DAO class.
On touch of a button on screen, i want to perform the below operations in a transaction:

1. Update the database record represent by by object a1(of class A)
2. Create a new database record for object a2(of class A)

The only option i can think of is doing it in the fragment itself as :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new MySQLiteOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
DaoForA dao = new DaoForA();
dao.update(a1);
dao.insert(a2);
db.endTransaction();
```

This results in the data layer code littering the fragment. I do not want to dilute the DAO class by including this business logic in it either. Is there a cleaner alternative?

Answer (score 1):

When the two operations must be inside a transaction, then the transaction must be controlled from the code that calls these two operations.
(It is possible to have nested transactions, but in any case, it's the outermost transaction that is important.)

If you do not want this code in the fragment, put it into a function that you can move into another object, maybe a separate business logic object.
However, this code must be *somewhere*.

---

Please note that your code will always roll back all changes; the canonical form of transactions is as follows:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // ... do all the stuff ...
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```